# how to get data from Sqlite in revrese Order from Sqlite databse

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public ArrayList<Chat> fetchChatHistory(String senderId, String receiverId) {
        ArrayList<Chat> chatList = new ArrayList<Chat>();
        String where = "" + DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID_COLUMN
                + " in (?,?) AND "
                + DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_SENDER_ID_COLUMN + " in (?,?) "
        /*
         * +"("+DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID_COLUMN+"=? AND "
         * +DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_SENDER_ID_COLUMN+"=?)"
         */;
        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_TABLE_CONTENTURI, null, where,
                new String[] { senderId, receiverId, senderId, receiverId },
                DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_ID_COLUMN);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Chat chat = new Chat();
                chat.setRecieverID(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID_COLUMN)));
                chat.setSenderID(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_SENDER_ID_COLUMN)));
                chat.setMessage(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DataProviderConstants.MSG_COLUMN)));
                chat.setLat(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_LAT_COLUMN)));
                chat.setLon(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_LON_COLUMN)));
                int isunread = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DataProviderConstants.MSG_IS_UNREAD));
                chat.setIsUnread((isunread == 0 ? false : true));
                chat.setDelvired(true);
                chatList.add(chat);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return chatList;
    }
```

Using this code am able to fetch data from Sq-lite database in forward direction while i want to get in reverse Order i am using Collections.reverse but here giving Error i don't how to get data in reverse Order from Sq-lite in android there is missing Some thing please suggest me or help me .

Comment: you can query through `Order By id desc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `query` method, the last parameter is the "orderby". Change

```
 Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_TABLE_CONTENTURI, null, where,
                new String[] { senderId, receiverId, senderId, receiverId },
                DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_ID_COLUMN);
```

with

```
 Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_TABLE_CONTENTURI, null, where,
                new String[] { senderId, receiverId, senderId, receiverId },
                DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_ID_COLUMN+" DESC");
```

This will give you rows ordered by id, but in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
public ArrayList<Chat> fetchChatHistory(String senderId, String receiverId) {
        ArrayList<Chat> chatList = new ArrayList<Chat>();
        String where = "" + DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID_COLUMN
                + " in (?,?) AND "
                + DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_SENDER_ID_COLUMN + " in (?,?) "
        /*
         * +"("+DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID_COLUMN+"=? AND "
         * +DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_SENDER_ID_COLUMN+"=?)"
         */;
        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_TABLE_CONTENTURI, null, where,
                new String[] { senderId, receiverId, senderId, receiverId },
                DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_ID_COLUMN);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToLast()) {
            do {
                Chat chat = new Chat();
                chat.setRecieverID(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID_COLUMN)));
                chat.setSenderID(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_SENDER_ID_COLUMN)));
                chat.setMessage(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DataProviderConstants.MSG_COLUMN)));
                chat.setLat(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_LAT_COLUMN)));
                chat.setLon(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DataProviderConstants.MESSAGE_LON_COLUMN)));
                int isunread = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DataProviderConstants.MSG_IS_UNREAD));
                chat.setIsUnread((isunread == 0 ? false : true));
                chat.setDelvired(true);
                chatList.add(chat);
            } while (cursor.moveToPrevious());
        }
        return chatList;
    }
```

I have changed

```
cursor.moveToFirst()
```

to

```
cursor.moveToLast()
```

and

```
cursor.moveToNext()
```

to

```
cursor.moveToPrevious()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways
a) Using `DESC` as defined in the answer
b) Reversing the array `chatList`.
Just before your line `return chatList`;

Add this line

```
Collections.reverse(chatList );
return chatList ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per official [Android Documention](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)

```
getContentResolver().query(
    UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,   // The content URI of the words table
    mProjection,                        // The columns to return for each row
    mSelectionClause                    // Selection criteria
    mSelectionArgs,                     // Selection criteria
    mSortOrder);
```

Notice mSorOrder when you specify `ORDER BY ID DESC/ASC`

Answer (score -2):

Just use raw query. Which is similar to other query language.

String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE ANY_CONDITION ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME DESC;";

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);